# Force the scrollbar over the page content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I wonder if there is a way, via css or javascript, to force the scrollbar to appear on top of the website content (like z-index 9999), instead of moving all the elements to the left ? 
My design include a blank space on the left no matter the resolution or screen size, so it would not be a problem, compared to the constant move left/move right imposed by the scrollbar when it appear/disappear.

If not I will simply get with the overflow-y:scroll method, but another solution would be good if possible :)

Thank you for your response !

Comment: Genuine question: why? It seems almost unimaginable that you have a site that is so special that it cannot abide by "how scrollbars work in desktop browsers" =)

Comment: The site has nothing special, it's just that there is several animations/transitions in javascript and the fact that the scrollbar move all to the left/right whenever it appears/disappears seem really visually annoying to me, so I was just wondering if there was a built-in or simple way not to abide how scrollbars work, but to maybe use another way they can work :)

Answer (score 0):

As Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans has already mentioned... the scrollbar moving content around is pretty basic browser behavior which should not really bother anyone. Nonetheless, we can make it appear as though the scrollbar appears above the content by using some js or jquery.

The idea would be to add padding to replace the scrollbar while your content is not overflowing. So for example:

```
// If there is no scrollbar, add some padding to replace it.
if ($(document).height() > $(window).height()) {
    $('body').css('padding', 'none');
} else {
    $('body').css('padding', '0 '+scrollbarwidth+'px 0 0');
}
```

See this [***jsfiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/pmarrL9z/1/) for a working example.

*Note: There is some flickering while resizing that I could not fix. It seems to have something to do with the window width. Maybe someone else can figure out what is causing this.*